# Estimating progress on plots

Tags: plotting, monitoring

When plotting a slow function, it would be nice to know how much of the work has already be done. However due to the refinement algorithm, simply monitoring the integration variable doesn't give an useful estimate unless `MaxRecursion` is set to 0 (and it's clear that the best I can hope for is an estimate). For example, consider

```
Monitor[Plot[Pause[0.01];Sin[x],{x,0,100}],x]
```

This goes through the interval dozens of times, although the number of points in each iteration goes down.

Therefore my question: Is there any way to get a reasonable estimate of how much of a plot is already done?

Comment: Interesting question.  The problem is that you can't predict how many points will be added in each refinement step.  Here's a [refinement function](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4695022#4695022) to experiment with, if you like.  I've been using both this code as well as a 2D version of it with a very slow to compute function, and from experience: the number of points added depends very much on the function: it could increase exponentially or stay near-constant.

Comment: However, if you *know your function well* (as I did), you'll be able to take good guesses.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Is that the algorithm `Plot` uses, or is it an alternative sampling algorithm to be used instead for a self-written `Plot` replacement?

Comment: I don't know the precise details, and my memory is not great, but from what I remember I read before, `Plot` should use either the same or a very similar algorithm, with a threshold angle of 5 degrees.  It will refine the sampling grid if the angle between tho consecutive line segments exceeds 5 degrees. (The code is mine, I didn't take it from `Plot`)

Comment: @Szabolcs and celtschk: the old package `Graphics\`Spline\` ` featured a set of subroutines that were essentially explicit reimplementations of the algorithm used within `Plot[]`/`ParametricPlot[]`. You might wish to take a look at them.

Comment: Progress bars are notoriously difficult to code. Maybe that's why Microsoft stopped using them in the update procedure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're willing to sacrifice automaticity on `MaxRecursions`, you could do this

```
SetAttributes[celtschkPlot, HoldAll];
celtschkPlot[fun_, {v_, r1__}, mr_: 6, op : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{i = 0, xant},
  Monitor[
   Plot[fun, {v, r1},
    MaxRecursion -> mr,
    EvaluationMonitor :> (If[v < xant, ++i]; xant = v), op],
   ProgressIndicator[i, {0, 2^mr}]]]
```

So, try

```
celtschkPlot[Pause[0.001]; Sin[2 Pi t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

and play with the functions. The last argument specifies the max recursion with defaults to a hard 6

```
celtschkPlot[Pause[0.001]; Sin[2 Pi t], {t, 0, 10}, 6]
```

This would be an upper bound. You could get the happy surprise that the plot finishes early

Comment: As an alternative you could use `EvaluationMonitor :> (If[v<ant, i++]; xant = v)`.

Comment: @Heike, thank god I have an alternative. My code is disgusting

Comment: @Heike, there we go, thanks

Comment: I wanted to give a counterexample or the computation steps growing exponentially, but it turned out that even in my example they do exactly that ... `ListPlot[Reverse@
  Table[Part[
    Reap@Plot[1/(1 + Exp[-10 x]), {x, -3, 3}, Mesh -> All, 
      EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[x], MaxRecursion -> k], 2, 1], {k, 0, 
    3}], PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: @Szabolcs, in any case, if it works for most cases, even when you don't know in which, it's probably good enough to be useful as an "estimate" I think

Comment: Thanks, that's a quite nice solution. Indeed I *am* willing to sacrifice automaticity on `MaxRecursion` because for those plots where it matters I have to do that anyway to get my plot in a reasonable time.

Comment: Thanks for the accept @celtschk, I hope it was not because of the function name. I'll be editing the "which I you're probably not" out

Comment: Of course it was not because of the function name. I did a few tests, and surprisingly often the progress bar gives a quite good estimate.

Comment: BTW, further experiments make me think that the automatic `MaxRecursion` for `Plot` is just 6 anyway.